# Using a mysql data base to populate a second drop down box automatically based off of first drop down box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I need to have a selection box display options that are based off of the selection from the drop down box right above it.  Once the user selects the Car Make, then I want the Car Models of the car make to be options to be selected.

I have been able to get the car makes options to be displayed from my mysql data base, but now I need the car models of only that make. My data base has two collumns, one for the Make and one for the Model.

The top section of PHP is the way i get the make, and the bottom is my attempt to get the model, but it displays hundreds of models, instead of just the few I want. I heard that AJAX or javascript can automatically upload the results, which would be nice. Any help is great. thanks!

```
</div>

<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', '*****', '******');
    mysql_select_db('*************');
    $sql = "SELECT Make FROM CarMakes";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<select name='carmake3'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['Make'] . "'>" . $row['Make'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', '******', '**********');
    mysql_select_db('*************');
    $sql = "SELECT Model FROM myTable";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<select class='modelbox' name='carmodel3'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['Model'] . "'>" . $row['Model'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="text" maxlength="4" name="car3year" placeholder="year" class="WriteInBox"/>

<input type="text" maxlength="6" name="car3miles" placeholder="miles" class="WriteInBox"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT Model FROM myTable";
```

This clearly is giving you the results you are asking for. It will select all models.

Your sql should look like

```
$sql = "SELECT Model FROM myTable WHERE Make='Make'";
```

The where limits you to retrieve only models associated with the specific Make you have selected.

To do it with AJAX, are you using jQuery? Straight JavaScript with an Ajax call? Please provide more information for answering that part of your question.

Comment: I heard that if I use php only, the page will have to be refreshed each time the first drop down box is selected so that the options in the second box are refreshed. I heard that AJAX will make it so that the page does not have to refresh.

Comment: Using Ajax will refresh data without refreshing the page. I suggest using jQuery for your ajax calls as it simplifies the process in making an ajax request. On request ajax would make a call to the php script and then you update content with new data.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best way to do this, but when I have had to do things like this before, I usually use the php to populate some javascript variables in my header and then use javascript to create the selects.  Also, I'm assuming that there is something in your database that maps certain models to certain makes of vehicles.

```
<script>
var makes = new Array();
var models = new Array();
<?php
$sql = "SELECT Make FROM CarMakes";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    makes[] = <?php echo json_encode($row['Make']); ?>;
<?php
}
$sql = "SELECT Make FROM CarMakes";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
    models[] = <?php echo json_encode($row['Model']); ?>;
<?php
}
?>
</script>
```

From here, you can create the selects and populate the options of the first one with the elements of the makes array.  Then add an onChange event to the first select to populate the second select.

EDIT For select creation:

```
<select id="make-select" onChange="updateModels()">
</select>
<select id="model-select">
</select>
<script>
$(function() {
    $.each(makes, function (index, value) {
        $(#make-select).append($('<option>') {
            value: value,
            text: value
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Then just create a function that called `updateModels` that will update `model-select` based on the selected value of `make-select`.  Again, you'll need somehting that associates models with makes in your database, and then you might have to make the `makes` variable an object instead of just an array.

```
var models = new Object()
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT Model-Make, Model FROM CarMakes";
    ...
    models.make = <?php echo json_encode($row['Model-Make']); ?>;
    models.model = <?php echo json_encode($row['Model']); ?>;
    ...
?>
```

Comment: how would I do that (add the "on change" part)? I am very new to Jquery, and I know how to do functions and all... like the on change, but how do i include it into the options and selector? thanks for helping!

Comment: See the above edit for more information on the jQuery and selects.